# Ring of integers of $K=\Bbb Q(a)$ with $ a^3=a+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I am trying to find $ \mathcal O_K$ and my guess is that $ \mathcal O_K= \Bbb Z [a]$ as we have $ \Bbb Z [a] \subset \mathcal O_K$ but I don't see how to proceed with the other inclusion.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you know about discriminants? Can you compute the discriminant of the basis $1, a, a^2$?

Comment: Yes I can compute the discriminant. Do I have to check it is square free?

Comment: Yes. If the discriminant is square free, then $(1, a, a^2)$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $\mathcal{O}_K$, which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you! Is it an equivalence in general? That a family is an integral basis iff its discriminant is square free?

Comment: It is not exactly an equivalence but an implication, see reuns comment. Given any $K$-basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ of elements of $\mathcal{O}_K$ of a number field $K$, the discriminant of $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is equal to $(\bigoplus_i \mathbb{Z}e_i : \mathcal{O}_K)^2D_K$ where $(\bigoplus_i \mathbb{Z}e_i : \mathcal{O}_K)$ is the index of $\bigoplus_i \mathbb{Z}e_i$ as a subgroup of $\mathcal{O}_K$ and $D_K$ is the discriminant of $K$. Hence if the discriminant of $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ is square-free, this index must be $1$ and then $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is an integral basis.

Comment: The discriminant of an order $\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\Bbb{Z}$ is the determinant of $B^\top B$ where $B_{ij} = \sigma_i(a_j)$, if you replace the order by a suborder then you replace $B$ by $BM$ for some $M\in M_n(\Bbb{Z})$ so the discriminant becomes $\det(M^2) \det(B^\top B)$.  Thus $Disc(O)$ squarefree implies $O=O_K$.  Then you need to show the discriminant of a monogenic order is also the discriminant of the minimal polynomial $Disc(f)=\prod_{i \ne j} (\alpha_i-\alpha_j)$. There is no equivalence : the discriminant of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is $(i-(-i))((-i)-i) =-4$.

Comment: Thank you reuns and Robin for your explanation and counter example for the equivalence. In a previous exercise, we showed that the discriminant of minimal polynomial=disc of monogenic order so I found $disc(k)=-4.1^3-27(-1)^2=-31$ which is square free and so QED.